# Convert Excel Date to Sql Server Date Time format using ACE Provider VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am attempting to import data in a batch from an Excel Worksheet to a Sql Server database.  Everything works except for the one date field in the spreadsheet.  The date returned is off by four years from the value in the spreadsheet.
Example: The Excel sheet has a date `10/24/2010 14:18`, but when I look at the column in my query, the date is `10/23/2006 2:18`.  This pattern, 4 years and 1 day earlier, is repeated for every row in the worksheet.

The Excel column comes to me as a custom type, formatted `m/d/yyyy h:mm`.  I receive this from an outside vendor and having them change the column is not going to be my simplest solution.  I'm hoping that someone has worked with this and can point me in the right direction.

For what it's worth, the relevent part of the query is:

> Select [Date Created] From MyWorksheet

TIA.

Comment: Well, this is embarassing.  Apparently in a fumble-fingered moment on my phone I voted this question down.  This morning I got a message from SO saying "congrats you've earned the critic badge" (for my 1st down vote).  I like badges, but I have nothing against this question.  I tried reversing it by up-voting, but get a message saying can't do so unless the question is edited.

Comment: @Doug edited, so you can reverse your vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the spreadsheet is generated from a Macintosh, or some other computer which uses the 1904 date system by default.  See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162) for more info.

As to the solution, you could try switching the date system for the workbook before doing the import.  I've never had to deal with this, so can't be sure it will work, but here's the VBA command to do that:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Date1904 = True
```

Or, as stated in the article linked above, you can just add 1,462 to each date.

EDIT: I realized that changing the date system, as I suggested above, will just move the problem up in your process, so that the error is apparent in Excel.  I think adding 1,462 (or 4 years and 1 day) to each date is the only solution.

Comment: While _changing_ the Date system setting may not be wise, you can _test_ it and adjust the query on the result `If MyWorksheet.Date1904 Then Select [Date Created] From MyWorksheet Else Select DateAdd(dd,1, DateAdd(yy,4,[Date Created])) From MyWorksheet End If`

Comment: I should have added that this was not a Mac, but the 1462 solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's that consistent, you can just do this:

```
Select DateAdd(dd,1, DateAdd(yy,4,[Date Created])) From MyWorksheet
```

Of course, you have to be sure this happens for *every* row in the column and it would be preferable to find the cause of the issue and fix that.  I'm also not sure exactly at what level the dataadd function will run here.  It sql server does it after pulling the data, you will be fine.  But if sql server passes this to excel as an ole query then the dateadd function calls need to be tweaked a bit.  HTH